# Problem with acces to function with react javascript child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

They would like to function from the component from the child component. This method call: TypeError: *Pizza__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.default.valid is not a function.

I try to add static function but  it will not get the value.
I can add code of pizza to orders, but this not I will.

Can anyone help?

I want to get dish_details from Pizza and Show Pizza form underneath.
In  .js no .tsx

Parend class:

```
class Orders extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.order = {
   name: "",
   preparation_time: "00:00:00",
   type: "",
 }
}


kind(){
 switch (this.order.type) {
  case 'pizza':
    return <Pizza/>;
 }
}

submit(){
console.log(Pizza.dishDetails()); // return error
}



render() {
 return (<div>
  <div>{this.state.selected ? this.kind() : ""}</div>
    <button className={styles.order_submit} onClick={this.submit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Kids class:

```
class Pizza extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        noOfSlices : 0,
        diameter : 0
    }
  }


  dishDetails(){
    return this.state;
}


noOfSlices(e){
    this.setState({noOfSlices : e.target.value});
}
```

Comment: It was a little bit hard to follow what the problem is. Could you try rephrasing to make it clearer? I understood you have an issue where you get an error in the console saying _something_ is not a function?

Comment: I rephrasing  my question.

Comment: Ah, I realized this has nothing to do with React, but is just a plain js problem. I see the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answer. I create clas Static with static value, and this is working for me.
static

```
class Static {
static defaultProps = {}
 }

export default Static;
```

order

```
 submit(){
     console.log(Static.defaultProps)
```

pizza

```
  noOfSlices(e){
    Static.defaultProps = {noOfSlices : e.target.value};
   }
```

Comment: A man gets his head and it is that simple

Answer (score 0):

If you want your components to have a state you need to declare it with

**this.state.[the name of the variable]**

That's how react knows that you want to store state inside a component. The error you get probably is because you declared the state of the pizza component wrongly

```
dish_details = {       //Not correct
    noOfSlices : 0,
    diameter : 0
}
```

Here you declare it inside the constructor, and that is correct, but in order to work you need to use the component state.

```
 constructor(props) { /
  super(props);

  this.state.order = {
   name: "",
   preparation_time: "00:00:00",
   type: "",
 }
}
```

Check out the docs on [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class).

Comment: Problem is not to asing to property. I try with constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
            noOfSlices : 0,
            diameter : 0
        }
      } but I can't use function from class Pizza. When I changing value and try to show it in consol from class Pizza is ok. But I cant use this in Orders.  Even I use static dishDetails, then I can use but this can't working.

Comment: I rephrasing  my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here

1. you say something is static, but you have not *created* a static function!

```
submit(){
console.log(Pizza.dishDetails()); // return error or undefined when static    
}
```

This is a call to a *static* function. To create a static function you would do this:

```
// ES5
Pizza.dishDetails = function(){ /* do something that does not touch `this` */ }
```

or in modern ES2015+:

```
class Pizza {
  static dishDetailsfunction(){ 
    /* do something that does not touch `this` */ 
  }
}
```

2. The `dishDetailsfunction` function *is* not static, but more importantly, it *cannot* be static, since it uses `this`. A static function has no reference to `this` - that's the definition of *static*.

So you need to reorganize a bit ...

You are not allowed to access the inner state of a component from an outer component, so you need to either do your data and external actions handling *outside* of your components (like Redux), use some kind of callback logic, or delegate the logic for handling submits down to `Pizza`.

Here is one way to do it using a callback:

In the order component

```
renderPizza() {
  // the `this` in the callback references the Orders (parent) component
  return <Pizza onChange={(pizzaOrder) => this.setState({order: pizzaOrder}) }/>} />
}
```

In the pizza component:

```
updateNoOfSlices(e){
    this.setState({noOfSlices : e.target.value});
    this.prop.onChange({this.state});
}
```

I removed all the logic that is not necessary for the point, but you should see how a callback solves this easily.

P.S. If you centralize your data handling in *one* place (for instance a component) you will get simpler and more easily testable code. For instance, you can remove all state from the `Pizza` class and just let it have `noOfSlices` and `diameter` passed to it as props from the Orders class.

Comment: I know I can't use statioc. I wrote becouse I try this and have this same conlusion of can't use this.  But I need to send this to parent. How I can?

Comment: @MariuszSzczerba I am updating the answer - I am not finished. Wait a while :)

Comment: How to do outside of components? Because I wanted to avoid copying the logic to the orders class.

Comment: @MariuszSzczerba I added an example that shows how a callback handles this in an elegant fashion.

Comment: What doing renderPizza?

Comment: `renderPizza` renders the pizza. You see its entire definition, so I am not sure exactly what you are wondering about? You would use it where you use `<Pizza />` today, like in the `kind()` method. Instead of `return <Pizza/>;` you have `return this.renderPizza()`.